# How to add individual layer on esri map

Tags: android

I have an esri map and I have to draw some layers on that. When I am adding a ArcGISTilesMapServiceLayer, then it is added perfectly. But when I try to add a specific layer by applying :

arcGisTiledLayer.getAllLayers()[1]

then this lines gives me null.
I mean, when I am trying to call getAllLayers() or getLayers() on ArcGISTilesMapServiceLayer object, it gives me null instead of AucGISLayeInfo[].

Where I am wrong just tell Me... Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
var layerOne = "some layer";

map.addLayer(new esri.layers.ArcGISTiledMapSrviceLayer(layerOne))
```